# Join Count to the original DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Give Data Frame as

```
import pandas as pd 
lst = ['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe', 'Yes', 'No', 'Maybe', 'Yes'] 
lst2 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77] 
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst, lst2)), 
               columns =['Name', 'val'])
```

I used to below to get GroupBy Count

```
countData=df.groupby("Name")["Name"].count()
countData
```

> Name
>
> Maybe    2
>
> No       2
>
> Yes      3

How to join the countData with DF ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transform`:

```
df['countData'] = df.groupby("Name")["Name"].transform(lambda x: x.count())
```

df:

```
    Name    val countData
0   Yes     11  3
1   No      22  2
2   Maybe   33  2
3   Yes     44  3
4   No      55  2
5   Maybe   66  2
6   Yes     77  3
```

Comment: Small possible improvent, you can use `.transform(pd.Series.count)` instead, and thus omit the lambda expression. +1 anyway :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well, improvement on the improvement. Why declare the function object itself if pandas accepts `str` args? `.transform('count')` avoids it all ;p

Comment: Expanding on what @rafaelc said, passing the function directly is much less performant than passing the string.  Under the hood I believe the latter calls `apply` rather than using the vectorized `count` that will be inferred from the string.

Comment: I was slightly off about the `apply`.  If you pass the string, it gets picked up by [this transform](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L1023) and returns `_transform_fast` since count is a reduction.  Otherwise, it gets applied as a lambda function to each group [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L1045).  Almost as bad as `apply`

Comment: @Willem, or some one else, please post the code as comment or answer

Answer (score 3):

You can set the index of `df`, then assign the counts and then reset then index:

```
count_data = df['Name'].value_counts()
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
df['count'] = count_data
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

This then gives us:

```
>>> df
    Name  val  count
0    Yes   11      3
1     No   22      2
2  Maybe   33      2
3    Yes   44      3
4     No   55      2
5  Maybe   66      2
6    Yes   77      3
```